# installation failed fedora dual boot with Ubuntu. Now, How to recover grub for ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, mbr

I have Ubuntu 20.10 installed and today I decided to install Fedora in one of my HDD partition.

Installation failed but
Error for grub came out.
Now I can't boot into Ubuntu.

How to recover Grub from my Fedora Live usb stick for Ubuntu to boot